# How to append 2 buttons on a data-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 buttons that I want to use in the same column, I create my buttons like this from a ajax response:

```
.done(function (data) {
    qmissedTable.bootstrapTable('hideLoading');
    data.forEach(function (missedEntry) {
        qmissedTable.bootstrapTable('append', {
            product_id: missedEntry.id,
            product_weight: missedEntry.weight,
            product_added_date: missedEntry.added_date,
            product_modified_date: missedEntry.modified_date,
            button_1: "<button type=\"button\" class=\"getid btn btn-default image\" data-id=\"" + missedEntry.id + "\" >Select</button>",
            button_2: "<button type=\"button\" class=\"getid btn btn-default tara\"  onclick=\"onAddMissedEntryInfoClicked(" + missedEntry.id + ")\">Select</button>"
        });
    }
    );
```

Now button_1 and button_2 I want to have them in same column under the Insert Tara/Harvest column, this is my view:

```
 <table id="scale_missed_entries"
                   data-toggle="table"
                   data-pagination="true" 
                   >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>                           
                        <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
                        <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
                        <th data-field="product_modified_date">Modified date</th>
                        <th data-field="button_1">Tara Image</th>
                        <th data-field="button_2 | button_1">Insert Tara/Harvest</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
 </table>
```

I try'ed with **data-field="button_2 | button_1"** but I think it can't take 2 arguments, is there another way around? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
$('th[data-field="button_2 | button_1"]').append("Your button")
```

you can select data-field as you was writing and use append function

Comment: I didn't got the .append("Your button") part in jquery, for what is used, where should I append that ?